# Change image border in roSpringboardScreen

Tags: roku, brightscript

In Roku BrightScript, is there any way to change the border around the image ("Poster") in the [roSpringboardScreen](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roSpringboardScreen)?

It is possible to change the focus border in the `roGridScreen` through the attribute `GridScreenFocusBorderHD` in [roAppManager](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roAppManager), but there appears to be no similar feature to set a custom image for the border in the `roSpringboardScreen`.

Even disabling the poster border would be an improvement over the default poster border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received the following answer at the [Roku developer forum](http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=87670#p494580):

*"I don't believe so. Not for springboard or poster screen,."*